# Is there an option to determine if user received personalized ranking or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I am using [GetPersonalizedRanking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/API_RS_GetPersonalizedRanking.html) function from AWS SDK.

I wonder if there's an option to determine if particular user really got personalized ranking or not. I can provide any data as `userId` and AWS Personalize will rerank the results. I would like to understand if there's any option to get info that re-ranked results were generically reranked or it was based on interactions data.

In best case scenario I would like to know for which users I have enough interactions data, which enable me to get truly personalized ranking (and for users which don't have enough data, don't send request to AWS at all).

Does anyone have experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

Ranking of items can be influenced by the following data elements: historical interactions for the user and other users, contextual metadata provided at inference and with historical interactions, item metadata at the last full training, and user metadata available at the last full retraining. The primary influence on ranking, however, is from interactions for the user. With that said, there is no way to tell from the GetPersonalizedRanking response which of those sources of data for the user were available to the model. To know with certainty, you'd have to track this outside of Personalize.